# float div if there is no space beneath it

Tags: html, css

So let's say I have 3 div's. I want them stacked in columns, next to each other. In the first columns, the first two div's fit. Now I want the third one to go next to the first one, since there is no room for the the third one to fit under the first two. How can this be done?

[image]

[image]

Comment: A rough diagram will help. Its not possible to answer by question only

Comment: I think you mean columns instead of rows since you refer to "next to" instead of below

Comment: if you know the size of divs you can use absolute positioning

Comment: But i will not know the amount of divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the only solid way to do this is to use CSS3's columns. See here for a reference: http://www.css3.info/preview/multi-column-layout/

This isn't widely supported yet (especially by IE), so you might need the jQuery plugin Columnizer to add more support:
http://dotmac.rationalmind.net/2011/03/cross-browser-multi-columns-with-jquery-and-css3/

Comment: Okay, it works, but not completely. When I divide them into columns, it works fine. But I have to specify a width, and an overflow-y:auto, and then it looks like the second screenshot. http://imgur.com/a/KBbQg

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
  #wrapper{
      width:960px;
      margin:0 auto;
    }
    .mydivs{
    float:left;
    }
    .cl{
       clear:left;
    }
```

**Markup:**

```
 <div id='wrapper'>
    <div class='mydivs'></div>

    <div class='mydivs'></div>

    <div class='mydivs'></div>
    <div class='cl'></div>
</div>
```

`float:left` all your divs and they will be position as you want.( Aligned left and in next row if there's no space left)

Comment: If I'mn correct, the question was how to stack them so that it fills each column first, then go to the next.
Your solution fills a row first, then goes to the next row.